# Postgres - how to 'print' a variable within a function (similar to python)?

Tags: postgresql, debugging

How to `print(var)` in postgres like python?

Given the following code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_sum(c1 integer, c2 integer)
RETURNS integer AS 
$$
    SELECT c1 + c2;
$$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE aggregate agg_custom_sum(integer) (
    sfunc = custom_sum,
    stype = integer,
    initcond = 0
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aggcheck;
CREATE TABLE aggcheck AS 
SELECT x FROM generate_series(1, 3) AS g(x);

SELECT agg_custom_sum(x) FROM aggcheck;
```

How can I print the values of `c1, c2` to the terminal when running?

Eg (I'm aware this won't work - it's python syntax - hopefully communicates the sort of usage I'm after though):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_sum(c1 integer, c2 integer)
RETURNS integer AS 
$$
    print(f"c1 = {c1}, c2 = {c2}"); 
    SELECT c1 + c2;
$$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

If it makes much difference - I'm calling this using `\i script.sql` from within a psql session.

If there are any links to debugging approaches more generally (eg breakpoing, try/catch, writing to a file) they would be appreciated, though not necessary to answer this question.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE - but that only works in PL/pgSQL, not SQL

Answer (score 2):

From SQL, you can use pg_notify to send yourself messages. You will need to LISTEN to the channel you are using, in order to receive the messages.  (This is unlike RAISE in pl/pgsql, where they are delivered to yourself automatically.)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_sum(c1 integer, c2 integer)
RETURNS integer AS
$$
    with t as (select  pg_notify('notice',(c1+c2)::text)) SELECT c1 + c2 from t;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;

LISTEN notice;
SELECT agg_custom_sum(x) FROM aggcheck;
 agg_custom_sum
----------------
              6
(1 row)

Time: 0.778 ms
Asynchronous notification "notice" with payload "1" received from server process with PID 48331.
Asynchronous notification "notice" with payload "3" received from server process with PID 48331.
Asynchronous notification "notice" with payload "6" received from server process with PID 48331.
```

Importantly, the notices will not arrive until the statement (and transaction) is finished, so it is not a "real time" monitoring.

But you should probably just convert your function into plpgsql and use RAISE, as that doesn't require the LISTEN and does respond in real time:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_sum(c1 integer, c2 integer)
RETURNS integer AS
$$ 
  begin 
    raise notice '%', (c1+c2);
    return c1 + c2; 
  END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgSQL;
```